# How can I print the SQL to set up the database from a single bundle

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine-orm, entity

So if I was to use the command:

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:create --dump-sql
```

I can see all the SQL that would be used to set up anything required in the database to run this Symfony project.

However, I have some vendor bundles that set up tables as well. I would like to see the SQL that would be run for just one of these bundles, how can I filter this command to just look at the one bundle? Or maybe just the one entity (not one entity manager as they use the default em, not a custom one).

Comment: I doubt that there is a command to filter the schema update to a single bundle however you can run the command `php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql` to see what query is about to be run. That will give you an idea what is about to be changed.

Comment: Yeh, the create is what I am using (as per the question). Just dumps a pretty big sql statement, was wanting to narrow it down to an entity or bundle if there is an option. If not maybe it could be a feature request for Doctrine.